# Cannot add to a collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make it so that a user is able to add `ingredient` to a listbox.

Here is a brief description of the relevant classes:

> `RecipeForm` is the form.
>
> `RecipeManager` is a collection manager class for `Recipe`
>
> `Recipe` is the "content" class where the fields `ingredients` are
>
> `ListManager`is the generic base class in which the manager class`RecipeManager` inherits from.

I want the user to input the ingredients of a `recipe` object.

And then save that object in an object of the `RecipeManager` in the `RecipeForm` class.

The list of `Recipe` objects saved in the collection (`m_foodManager` in the code below) is supposed to be displayed in a listbox in the `RecipeForm`

Here is how I tried it:

The form `FoodRegister`:

```
 public partial class FoodRegister : Form
  {
        private Recipe m_food = new Recipe();
        private RecipeManager m_foodmanager = new RecipeManager();


 public FoodRegister()
     {
            InitializeComponent();
     }

 private void ReadValues()
     {           
            m_food.Ingredients.Add(Ingredienttxt.Text);
     }

 private void UpdateResults()
     {
            ResultListlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list

            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < m_foodmanager.Count; index++)
          {  
                Recipe recipe = m_foodmanager.GetAt(index);
                //Adds to the list.
                ResultListlst.Items.Add(recipe);
                ResultListlst.DisplayMember = "Ingredients";
          }
     }

    private void Addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            Recipe recept = new Recipe();

            m_foodmanager.Add(recept);

            ReadValues();
            UpdateResults();
     }
}
```

`Recipe` class

```
public class Recipe
    {
        private ListManager<string> m_ingredients = new ListManager<string>();

        public ListManager<string> Ingredients
        {
            get { return m_ingredients; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}", this.Ingredients);
        }
    }
```

The `RecipeManager`class (This one is empty because it inherits its methods from `ListManager`.:

```
 public class RecipeManager : ListManager<Recipe>
    {
        public RecipeManager()
        {
        }
    }
```

The `ListManager` class:

```
  public class ListManager<T> : IListManager<T>
    {
        protected List<T> m_list;

        public ListManager()
        {
            m_list = new List<T>();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return m_list.Count; }
        }

        public  void Add(T aType)
        {
            m_list.Add(aType);
        }

        public void DeleteAt(int anIndex)
        {
            m_list.RemoveAt(anIndex);
        }

        public bool CheckIndex(int index)
        {
            return ((index >= 0) && (index < m_list.Count));
        }
  
        public T GetAt(int anIndex)
        {
            if (CheckIndex(anIndex))
                return m_list[anIndex];
            else 


                 return default(T);
       }

       public override string ToString()

        {

        if(m_list != null && m_list.Any())
       {
             return string.Join(", ", m_list);
       }

        return string.Empty;
       }
}
```

**The problem** is that nothing is displayed on the listbox, its adding empty strings. I'm not sure if I add strings to the collection properly. I want the user to add strings to the collection by inputting values to the textbox

Comment: Do more debugging to narrow down the problem.  Add some debugging test to your `ToString()` overloads and see if anything jumps out.  Run the code line-by-line to verify that the functions are being called the way yo expect.

Comment: You're not using `m_food` but a local `Recipe` in `Addbtn_Click`. Get rid of `m_food` and add a `Recipe` parameter to `ReadValues`.

Comment: @bstenzel Thank you!! It partly works. I does display the string on the listbox, but the problem now is that when the user adds another string to the listbox, all previous strings change to the same string.